# Spring + google cloud: No qualifying bean of type 'com.google.cloud.storage.Storage' available

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, spring-cloud-gcp

I am trying to use spring library for google cloud API:

**spring-cloud-gcp-starter-vision**

But Spring Application Context fails to load with an error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentOcrTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/vision/CloudVisionAutoConfiguration$VisionOcrConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'documentOcrTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.google.cloud.storage.Storage' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}...

I'm not sure how I can handle it since it's all google's code, nothing in my own code.

Just for the information, this is the way I'm trying to use this library:

```
@Service
public class OCRServiceImpl implements OCRService {

    private static Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(OCRServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private CloudVisionTemplate cloudVisionTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

Comment: it is weird the fact that on local it works, once  put on a container in GCP throws UnsatisfiedDependencyException, i checked the constructor of  CloudVisionTemplate and it has ImageAnnotatorClient. how about scanning this package ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set spring.cloud.gcp.vision  ?

```
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.cloud.gcp.vision")
```

and have a look @CloudVisionAutoConfiguration

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public CloudVisionTemplate cloudVisionTemplate(ImageAnnotatorClient imageAnnotatorClient) {
        return new CloudVisionTemplate(imageAnnotatorClient);
    }
```

Looks like you are missing the properties configuration!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add *both* the spring-cloud-gcp-starter-vision and spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage to your dependencies.

See [cloud-vision-ocr-dependencies](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#cloud-vision-ocr-dependencies).